# jquery two different date validation

Tags: jquery

var cin = $("#datepicker").val();
    var cout = $("#datepicker2").val();
    dateformat is : dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy'

how do i use jquery to check cin(checkin) date not past cout(checkout) date? which means, cout date cannot earlier then cin date

Comment: Are you using the [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) or they are just two textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your datepicker is, but if it is a [JQuery-datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), then better get the date with `.datepicker("getDate")`. Then, you should have JS *Date* objects, that you can compare like normal numbers (see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)